# Работа BotMan с "чистым" Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Всем привет :)
Мне дали задачу создать telegram бота при помощи https://botman.io и Laravel. Важная особенность задачи botman подключить к "чистому" Laravel, а не создавать на основе BotMan Studio.
Такая возможность - есть, даже в документации есть раздел "Installation with Laravel" только там мне ничего не понятно, и информации очень мало у меня нет понимания как это сделать с 0.
Отзовитесь кто работал с етим, буду благодарен за советы/ссылки на туториалы если есть примеры с "чистым" PHP буду благодарен (я разберу примеры и сам подключу к Laravel)!
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: в документации ясно написано что если не хотите использовать botman studio то устанавливаете botman через composer и даже есть примеры использования в этом варианте

Comment: @varz62 они не полные и у меня не работали.

Comment: @Arzek https://gitlab.com/kdv/bot